# Tensorflow TensorBoard not showing acc, loss, acc_val, and loss_val only only epoch_accuracy and epoch_loss

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am looking to have a TensorBoard display graphs corresponding to acc, loss, acc_val, and loss_val but they do not appear for some reason. Here is what I am seeing.

[image]

I am looking to have this: 
[image]

I am following the instruction [here](https://www.dlology.com/blog/quick-guide-to-run-tensorboard-in-google-colab/#disqus_thread) to be able to use tensorboard in a google colab notebook

This is the code used to generate the tensorboard:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(NAME), 
                          histogram_freq=1, 
                          write_graph=True, 
                          write_grads=True, 
                          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
                          write_images=True)

model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

# Train model
history = model.fit(
     train_x, train_y,
     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
     epochs=EPOCHS,
     validation_data=(validation_x, validation_y),
     callbacks=[tensorboard]
)
```

How do I go about solving this issue? Any ideas? Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That's the intended behavior. If you want to log custom scalars such as a dynamic learning rate, you need to use the TensorFlow Summary API.

Retrain the regression model and log a custom learning rate. Here's how:

1. Create a file writer, using `tf.summary.create_file_writer()`.
2. Define a custom learning rate function. This will be passed to the Keras `LearningRateScheduler` callback.
3. Inside the learning rate function, use `tf.summary.scalar()` to log the custom learning rate.
4. Pass the `LearningRateScheduler` callback to `Model.fit()`.

In general, to log a custom scalar, you need to use `tf.summary.scalar()` with a file writer. The file writer is responsible for writing data for this run to the specified directory and is implicitly used when you use the `tf.summary.scalar()`.

```
logdir = "logs/scalars/" + datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir + "/metrics")
file_writer.set_as_default()

def lr_schedule(epoch):
  """
  Returns a custom learning rate that decreases as epochs progress.
  """
  learning_rate = 0.2
  if epoch > 10:
    learning_rate = 0.02
  if epoch > 20:
    learning_rate = 0.01
  if epoch > 50:
    learning_rate = 0.005

  tf.summary.scalar('learning rate', data=learning_rate, step=epoch)
  return learning_rate

lr_callback = keras.callbacks.LearningRateScheduler(lr_schedule)
tensorboard_callback = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(16, input_dim=1),
    keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(
    loss='mse', # keras.losses.mean_squared_error
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(),
)

training_history = model.fit(
    x_train, # input
    y_train, # output
    batch_size=train_size,
    verbose=0, # Suppress chatty output; use Tensorboard instead
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, lr_callback],
)
```

Comment: Hey! I really appreciate you taking the time to respond! However, I am kind of confused. I am not looking to implement a dynamic learning rate. I am looking to have graphs of acc, loss, acc_val, and loss_val. I have update my question include what I am looking to do so things are more clear!